# How to NOT select an element, when another certain NESTED element is preceded?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, negation

I am trying to select all `<ul>` elements that are **Not** preceded by a `<mark>` element directly **Nested in** a `<p>` element.

In other words, I want to only select `<ul>` elements that do not follow a paragraph `<p>` element bearing a `<mark>` element as their last child.

---

I have tried several things like `p:not(p > mark) + ul{}` and `p:not(p) > mark + ul{}`
But either the CSS rules select too much (all ul elements) or too little (no ul elements at all).

What have I overlooked?

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4e1ajqr8/)

```css
/* CSS */
/* Select ul elements that are not preceeded by a nested <mark> element as last child of the preceding paragraph p element */

p:not(p > mark) + ul{
  margin-top: 2em;
  }
```

```html
<p>
  Text Text Text
</p>

<ul>
  <!-- This ul element should BE selected -->
  <!-- There should be a margin above this list -->
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>


<hr>


<p>
  Text Text Text<br>
  <mark>Marker</mark><!-- Look out for this element inside preceding paragraph -->
</p>

<ul>
  <!-- This ul element should NOT be selected -->
  <!-- There should be NO margins above this list -->
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what you need is `:has()` but it *has* no support

Comment: To select an element based on its children you need the `:has` pseudo-class.

    `p:not(:has(>mark)) + ul`

However, this is a proposed feature with [no browser support at the time of writing](https://caniuse.com/?search=has). Change the HTML instead. Add a class to the paragraph.